# How do I find the automation parameters for Azure alerts?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-automation

I have setup an alert in the Azure portal for the average response time metric. Now I want to automate it so that this alert gets setup on each new deploy.
When I go to the Automation script tab under my resource group I can see that the alert metric has been added, but I can't find the alert criteria parameters, does anyone know where they are defined?

I have found this resource in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-create-metric-alerts-with-templates), which I have followed.

This part I can see in my automation script

```
"resources": [
    {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/resourcegroup-dev-weu/providers/microsoft.insights/metricAlerts/response-time-avg'.",
        "type": "microsoft.insights/metricAlerts",
        "name": "[parameters('metricAlerts_response_time_avg_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
        "location": "global",
        "tags": {},
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
            "description": "Alert if the response time get above 1 second on average for the last 1 minute, 1 minute intervals.",
            "severity": 3,
            "enabled": true,
            "scopes": [
                "/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/resourcegroup-dev-weu/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/webapp-dev-weu"
            ],
            "evaluationFrequency": "PT1M",
            "windowSize": "PT1M",
            "criteria": {
                "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.SingleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria"
            },
            "actions": [
                {
                    "actionGroupId": "[parameters('metricAlerts_response_time_avg_actionGroupId')]",
                    "webHookProperties": {}
                }
            ]
        },
        "dependsOn": []
    }
]
```

But this part I can't find

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "alertName": {
            "value": "New Metric Alert"
        },
        "alertDescription": {
            "value": "New metric alert created via template"
        },
        "alertSeverity": {
            "value":3
        },
        "isEnabled": {
            "value": true
        },
        "resourceId": {
            "value": "/subscriptions/replace-with-subscription-id/resourceGroups/replace-with-resourceGroup-name/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/replace-with-resource-name"
        },
        "metricName": {
            "value": "Percentage CPU"
        },
        "operator": {
             "value": "GreaterThan"
        },
        "threshold": {
            "value": "80"
        },
        "timeAggregation": {
            "value": "Average"
        },
        "actionGroupId": {
            "value": "/subscriptions/replace-with-subscription-id/resourceGroups/resource-group-name/providers/Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups/replace-with-action-group"
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error when I try to run it without the parameters defined:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 17:07:53 - Resource microsoft.insights/metricAlerts 'response-time-avg' failed with message '{
  "Code": "BadRequest",
  "Message": "Unable to find any of the requested metrics ''"
}'
```

Comment: If the reply is helpful, you could accept it or let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Will have a look now to see if I can get it to work, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can create an alert for a VM following your providing [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-create-metric-alerts-with-templates) via just replacing with the values of resourceId and actionGroupId in the parameter file. Deploy the template file and parameter file with PowerShell successfully.

[image]

After that, you can see the resource type `microsoft.insights/metricAlerts` in the Automation script tab. Once you create an alert, you can see the **criteria** properties and **criteria** parameter refer to the followings.

If you want to export the specific alert template instead of all resources in your current group. You can refer to these steps: Go to the **Resource group** page-under **Settings**-**Deployments**-Click the newly created alert **deployment name**. You will find the resources and parameters in the template and just download it. Get more details for [viewing template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-export-template#view-template-from-deployment-history).

[image]

### Update

With the same deployment as above, I can see the more of **criteria** parameters using the [Azure REST API](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metricalerts/get) as below. It seems that the automation tab does not show all the necessary info. The only way to get the full automation script is to use the Azure REST API to get Metric Alerts.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked to do it like this. I still have the issue with seeing the criteria parameters in the automation script after creating an alert in the portal manually. The reason I want to create it in the portal is to get all the parameters, but I guess doing it like this I just need to find all the valid parameter values in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, the parameter JSON file includes the parameters which you want to input your deployment when you deploy your template, you just need to refer to the valid parameter values in the documentation or in the automation script's parameter part.

Comment: @Nancy Xiong just for clarification. It doesn't matter what method you used to deploy. The ARM template should have the parameter and criteria regardless. Is that correct?

Comment: @Rthomas529  Yes, It doesn't matter what method you used to deploy. You will see the same in the template of Automation script tab.

Comment: Just to clarify, the automation tab does not show all the necessary info as of this date due to metrics alerts is so new it's not fully implemented in the portal yet. I noticed this when I was looking in the resource explorer (https://resources.azure.com), the only way to get the full automation script after manually creating a alert in the portal is to use the Azure REST API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metricalerts/get).

Comment: @KungWaz Thanks for sharing, I update this in my reply for more people reference. It's the same result no matter you manually create an alert or use a template to deploy an alert.

Comment: I used the Azure Az PowerShell commands:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/metrics/alert?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-metrics-alert-show